# $\forall K>0: \ P[\inf\{t>0:|B_t|>K\sqrt{t}\}=0]=1$ means that a.s. $B$ isn't Hölder-$\tfrac{1}{2}$ continuous at $t$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose that for every $K > 0$ we have that
$$
\mathrm{P} \left [\inf \left\{t >0: \left| B_t \right|> K \sqrt{t} \right \} = 0 \right] = 1,
$$
where $B$ is a Brownian Motion.

> I would like to motivate - from an explicit definition of Hölder-$\tfrac{1}{2}$ continuity - that this means that almost surely $B$ is not Hölder-$\tfrac{1}{2}$ continuous at $t$.

> Perhaps it is possible to show that $B$ isn't Hölder-$\tfrac{1}{2}$ continuous "from the right". This would be sufficient for the claim to be true and perhaps easier than my attempt at a solution below, since it would be easier to apply the property $B_t - B_s \sim B_{t-s}$?

**Here comes my long winded attempt to a solution:**

Given any $t$ we have that the path $B_s(\omega)$ is $\tfrac{1}{2}$-Hölder continuous at $t$ if there exists a $K>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that for
$$
|t-s| < \epsilon,
$$
it is the case that
$$
\left | B_t(\omega) - B_s(\omega) \right | \le K \sqrt{|t - s|}.
$$
We will try to use the fact that
$$
B_t - B_s \sim B_{t-s}.
$$
If we want to calculate the probability that $B$ is $\tfrac{1}{2}$-Hölder continuous at $t$, we have to consider that the $\epsilon$ in the above requirement may differ for different paths (the $K$ may of course also vary).

My idea was to start with an explicit expression for the event that $B_t$ is Hölder-$\tfrac{1}{2}$ continuous at $t$, and then show that the given probability means that the complement of this event has probability one. Thus the event that $B$ is $\tfrac{1}{2}$-Hölder continuous at $t$ may be written as,
$$
\bigcup_{K=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left \{\left | B_t - B_s \right | \le K \sqrt{|t - s|}:0< |t-s|<\frac{1}{n}  \right \}.
$$
Now,
$$
\left \{\left | B_t - B_s \right | \le K \sqrt{|t - s|}:0< |t-s|<\frac{1}{n}  \right \}
$$
is distributed as (Not $100 \%$ sure about  this)
$$
\left \{\left | B_{|t-s|}\right | \big/ \sqrt{|t - s|} \le K :0< |t-s|<\frac{1}{n}  \right \},
$$
and thus we may consider the event where $B$ is $\tfrac{1}{2}$-Hölder continuous at $t$ as
\begin{multline*}
\bigcup_{K=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left \{\left | B_{|t-s|}\right | \big/ \sqrt{|t - s|} \le K :0< |t-s|<\frac{1}{n}  \right \} \\
= \bigcup_{K=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left \{ \sup_{0 < |t-s| < \frac{1}{n} }\left |B_{|t-s|}\right | \big/ \sqrt{|t-s|} \le K  \right \} \\
=\bigcup_{K=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left \{ \sup_{0 < t < \frac{1}{n} }\left |B_{t}\right | \big/ \sqrt{t} \le K  \right \}.
\end{multline*}

If the above is correct, one may consider (a set that is distributed as) a subset of the the event that $B$ *isn't* $\tfrac{1}{2}$-Hölder continuous at $t$. We have that
$$
\left (\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left \{  \sup_{0<t \le \frac{1}{n} }\left |B_{t}\right | \big/ \sqrt{t} \le K \right \}\right ) ^C = \left \{\inf \left\{t >0: \left| B_t \right|> K \sqrt{t} \right \} = 0 \right \}. 
$$
Now,
$$
\left \{\inf \left\{t >0:  B_t > K \sqrt{t} \right \} = 0 \right \} \subset \left \{\inf \left\{t >0: \left| B_t \right|> K \sqrt{t} \right \} = 0 \right \},
$$
and so the given condition is sufficient for the desired conclusion as we have that a subset of the set where $B$ isn't Hölder-$\tfrac{1}{2}$ continuous has probability one.

*Most grateful for any help provided!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear from the question if you are having trouble proving the condition:
\begin{align}
P (\inf \{t>0\mid |B_t| > K\sqrt{t}\}=0)= 1 \text{ for all }K>0. \label{eq1} \tag{1}
\end{align}

But if you assume \eqref{eq1}, showing that $B$ is not Holder-$\frac{1}{2}$ continuous is not difficult. Clearly by the definition of Holder continuity, this condition says that $B$ is not Holder-$\frac{1}{2}$ continuous at $t=0$.

And now apply the Markov property of $B$. Fix $t>0$. If $B$ is a standard Brownian motion then so is the process $W_s = B_{s+t}-B_t$. Thus condition \eqref{eq1} holds for $(W_s)_{s\ge 0}$ and it is not Holder-$\frac{1}{2}$ continuous at $s=0$. This implies that $B$ is not Holder-$\frac{1}{2}$ continuous at $t$.